# Sum Query with same ID values no repeating

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SELECT s.[Statistics ID], s.[Player ID], s.[Game ID], s.[Season ID], s.[Goals Scored], s.[Assists Made], s.[Key Passes], s.[Successful Tackles], s.[Successful Interceptions], s.[Goals Conceded], p.[Player Name], p.[Player ID]
FROM Statistics$ s, Players$ p WHERE s.[Player ID]=p.[Player ID]
```

This is what shows up [on the preview](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t35.0-12/10927667_1007875799228000_1017620884_o.jpg?oh=a03b8c8ba8fa9acb0097c859b3b04787&oe=54BF3527&gda=1421878070_0c629e672cb8d6949bfc8bd8e71f0985)

Hey guys, so I'm having kind of a problem with this query, but what I want to happen is for all the values like Goals Scored, Assists Made,Key passes etc to sum up for each Player ID making them appear only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use aggregates such as [`GROUP BY`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm) and then `SUM(...)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.[Statistics ID], s.[Player ID], s.[Game ID], s.[Season ID], 
    p.[Player Name], Stats.*
FROM Statistics$ s
    JOIN Players$ p ON s.[Player ID] = p.[Player ID]
    JOIN (
        SELECT s.[Player ID], SUM(s.[Goals Scored]) AS GoalsScored, 
            SUM(s.[Assists Made]) AS AssistsMade, SUM(s.[Key Passes]) AS KeyPasses, 
            SUM(s.[Successful Tackles]) AS SuccessfulTackles, 
            SUM(s.[Successful Interceptions]) AS SuccessfulInterceptions, 
            SUM(s.[Goals Conceded]) AS GoalsConceded
        FROM Statistics$ s
        GROUP BY s.[Player ID]
    ) AS Stats ON Stats.[Player ID] = s.[Player ID]
```

Note that you have to use an aggregate function for any column that isn't in the `GROUP BY`, but you can join the results together with the player details as I have done above

Comment: This is what happens when i write your solution,do you know why? https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10937493_1007893572559556_575003104_n.jpg?oh=94957c18c526bd5a5cb92af50ebda69f&oe=54BFE7B6&__gda__=1421813606_d6dc68d4b0589524eabf096b648c10fa

Comment: @MirandaCode Please take note of my last sentence. You have to use this in an inner query if you want the details....I am guessing you are new to SQL and need the whole query then?

Comment: @MirandaCode Updated the code. I believe this should work...there might be better ways from a performance standpoint though. If this solves your problem, please don't forget to select it as the correct answer  via the checkmark :)